# How to get function trace for a deep neural network model written in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, trace

I have a problem where I need to record function trace for a neural network model.

I need to create a task graph of a neural network model written in tensorflow. I think adding logs in a tensorflow code first can solve my problem. However it is very time consuming. What can be the best way to solve this. Does tensorflow provide any facility to accomplish this task  Please help.

Comment: I guess you are looking for 'tensorboard'

Comment: will i get log of function traces in tensorboard

Comment: i am not sure as i have not dived much deep into its just a suggestion, you can give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tensorboard. I strongly recommend it. Because you can find the very detail of your model.

> writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(your-dir, sess.graph)

And open it in the Chrome.